# Can an array be created with a variable in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

In my computer science course I was told that only literals and named constants can be used to create an array, like

```
int[] myarray = new int[10];
```

or

```
final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
int[] myarray = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

The professor said that a changeable variable cannot be used to create an array, like

```
int arraysize = 10;
int[] myarray = new int[arraysize];
```

I thought that once an array is created, its size cannot be changed, therefore it wouldn't matter what is used to create it (a literal, named constant, or variable). Furthermore, doesn't the 'final' keyword only affect the variable (e.g. ARRAY_SIZE) and not the thing being assigned to it?

So why can't I use a variable (e.g. arraysize) to create an array?

My professor refuses to discuss this with me, therefore I brought the question here.

Comment: he is wrong....

Answer (score 0):

I see what you ask here, and I can tell why your professor told you this.
The main reason is that costant (final) Integers don't change in the whole code, so it will not change the dimension of the array in any way.

BUT
this doesn't mean you cannot use it
watch this code, which follows:

```
short numberOne =5;
int numberTwo = 5;
byte numberThree = 5;
final int NUMBER_FOUR = 5;
    
int[] arrayOne = new int[numberOne]; //short
int[] arrayTwo = new int[numberTwo]; //int
int[] arrayThree = new int[numberThree]; //byte
int[] arrayFour = new int[NUMBER_FOUR];  //final INT
```

all of these combination are validated and can be used, even if not final

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it is completely possible to create an array with the length as the variable, there's not anything inherently bad about it. It doesn't matter if the variable you used as length was declared as `final` or not, either.

Answer (score 0):

Your professor is wrong. The size used to initialize an array does not need to be a constant. If you really want to drive the point home, you can introduce randomness:

```
int samples = 6; // 6 proofs
int maxSize = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    int mysterySize = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(maxSize); // Random size
    int[] mysteryArray = new int[mysterySize];
    System.out.println("Mystery Array is size: " + mysteryArray.length);
}
```

Output:

```
Mystery Array is size: 38
Mystery Array is size: 13
Mystery Array is size: 81
Mystery Array is size: 27
Mystery Array is size: 37
Mystery Array is size: 40
```

Notice from this output that array size is in no way constant. It is true that *after* an array is initialized you cannot change its size. However, you can always create a new array of a variable size and copy elements from the original to the new one.

If you need a data type that can change its size, take a look at [`Lists`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Sets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and other [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).